# How to make a multiple line graph with each line data points coming from a different column?

Tags: r

How to make a multiple line graph with the following data:
Range Count Count2
1   0-25  2757  22253
2  25-50   220   1118
3  50-75   220     76
4 75-100     3     11

> 

X Axis to be Range, One line be 'Count' and another line be Count '2'
Also each line a different color?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `gather` in `tidyverse`  package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# generate the data
data <- tribble(
  ~Range, ~Count, ~Count2,
  "0-25", 2757, 22253,
  "25-50", 220, 1118,
  "50-75", 220, 76,
  "75-100", 3, 11)

# reshape the data
data_long <- data %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -Range)

# plot
data_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(factor(Range)), y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "Range", y = "Count") + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:length(data$Range),
    labels = data$Range
)
```

Here is the result:

[The Result](https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/008i3skNgy1gqmnj7bkjkj30yq0lcmzj.jpg)

For more details about `ggplot2` and make adjustments to other objects:

[R Graphics Cookbook, 2nd edition](https://r-graphics.org)

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way to keep the "0-25", "25-50", "50-75" and "75-100" on the x axis instead of the 1,2,3 and 4?

Comment: I just edited it. Hopefully you found this useful!